# Will AirPods Max play low-latency audio over USB connection to Mac?

Tags: airpods

Given AirPods Max connected via a USB-C to Lightning cable to a Mac - will it be able to play audio with (relatively) low latency over the USB connection?

Playing audio over Bluetooth has too high latency for my purpose (in the range of 175 ms). I know lower latency (in the range of 10 ms) audio is possible with the Lightning to 3.5 mm cable. However, I would like to be able to connect it to my Mac via USB directly.

An indication of whether or not audio playback works at all over USB would be great if it is not possible to quantify the latency in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After purchasing the AirPods Max, I can confirm that no - they do not support playing audio at all over the USB connection. Unfortunately.

When connected to a Mac, it is a requirement to use Bluetooth to transfer audio data to the headphones. The USB connection to the Mac is only used for charging.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect by wire using the lightning to 35mm audio cable...

https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MXK22AM/A/lightning-to-35-mm-audio-cable-12m-white

Comment: Given that I write exactly this in the question, it's not really an answer...